# NumPy -- ImportError: PyInit__multiarray_umath

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.x

I'm facing the below error while importing NumPy library. I have tried all of the suggestions advised by Python in its error log, but no luck.

Strangely, when I use Python's OS library and print the "PATH" environment variable, it appends the below automatically, which I don't find in the Windows `Environment Variable` GUI.
Afraid if it's a bug causing this.

```
;;C:\Users\test-apple\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\.libs
```

Error log --

```
Python 3.7.6 (tags/v3.7.6:43364a7ae0, Dec 19 2019, 00:42:30) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

>>> import os
>>> import numpy

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\test-apple\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "C:\Users\test-apple\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "C:\Users\test-apple\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 7, in <module>
    from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__multiarray_umath)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "C:\Users\test-apple\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "C:\Users\test-apple\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: 

IMPORTANT: PLEASE READ THIS FOR ADVICE ON HOW TO SOLVE THIS ISSUE!

Importing the numpy c-extensions failed.
- Try uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.
- If you have already done that, then:
  1. Check that you expected to use Python3.7 from "C:\Users\test-apple\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\pythonw.exe",
     and that you have no directories in your PATH or PYTHONPATH that can
     interfere with the Python and numpy version "1.18.0" you're trying to use.
  2. If (1) looks fine, you can open a new issue at
     https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues.  Please include details on:
     - how you installed Python
     - how you installed numpy
     - your operating system
     - whether or not you have multiple versions of Python installed
     - if you built from source, your compiler versions and ideally a build log

- If you're working with a numpy git repository, try `git clean -xdf`
  (removes all files not under version control) and rebuild numpy.

Note: this error has many possible causes, so please don't comment on
an existing issue about this - open a new one instead.

Original error was: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__multiarray_umath)

>>> 
>>>
```

Please advise if any prior experiencing this.

Comment: This question is a coding problem not a Data Science Problem

Comment: True. Two reasons (1) Don't have access to SO, and (2) since it's related to NumPy I thought could qualify for Data Science as well. Will be great if moderators can humbly move it to SO please.

Comment: if you are blocked from asking questions on SO it can't be moved

Comment: I personally find the un/blocking thing in SO quite ridiculous. Silly reasons that it can't be undone, etc. etc. There are 1000s of forums (tech and non-tech) but none has anything like this - where something done can't be reverted. Quite strange coz. ultimately it boils to the some table/column maintaining 0 or 1 flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't diagnose the actual reason behind this problem, but circumvented it by installing Anaconda - which comes with huge number of packages pre-installed.

If anything is missing, can be added using Conda or Pip installer. Anaconda has an excellent package manager.

So, if anyone in future (unfortunately) lands on this question, please have a look into Anaconda if it works for you.

Happy learning!